# I " grew up " to be a germaphobe

Tags: to-infinitive

In a recent NYT article, it says

> It’s no surprise, then, that I **grew up to be** a germaphobe too.

Does it have a similar meaning to " grow to be", like " She has grown to like him", which means she has gradually started to like him?

Answer (score 1):

No.  "Grow up" means "become an adult".  "Grow up to be a" is normally used to indicate a career or occupation you have as an adult, in a way that draws attention to the transition from being a child to an adult.  In this case though it's not a job, it's saying when she became an adult, she also became a "germaphobe" as in, she is afraid of germs.

So this could be read as:

> As an adult, I developed a fear of germs.

"Germaphobe" comes from looking at the technical terms for intense irrational fears like "arachnophobia" (Fear of arachnids like spiders and scorpions), "acrophobia" (fear of heights), or "claustrophobia" (Fear of confined spaces).  These are widely misused for much less intense or irrational fears and because many people don't know all the Greek based the technical terms, it's common to take the well known pattern of "something-phobe" and put in whatever "something" they want.  There is a word for a true, intensely irrational phobia of infectious disease and that's "mysophobia"  But most English speakers would not recognize it other than knowing its a fear of something.

Comment: Presumably the writer was encouraged to be afraid of germs _while_ they were growing up, and so continued to be phobic  as an adult.